# Graph API - Get nested drives

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

I am trying to retrieve a nested folder using the Graph API sdk in C# with the following folder structure:

```
(site) site.sharepoint.com -> (folder) 2022 -> (folder) October -> (folder) 25
```

Using this code:

```
var dayDrive = await graphClient
    .Sites["site.sharepoint.com"]
    .Drives["2022"]
    .Root
    .Children["October"]
    .Children["25"]
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

However this fails with code:

```
Code: invalidRequest
Message: Invalid request
```

But this doesn't make sense, why is this failing and how can I retrieve the nested folder I need?

Comment: since I don't have the same test resource with yours, so I shared 2 options, could you pls take a try? By the way, could you pls kindly let me know if it didn't work for you with the latest error message?

Comment: Drives["2022"] will not work. You need to use drive id, not name of the folder

Answer (score 0):

try

```
await graphClient.Sites["site.sharepoint.com"].Drives["2022"]
                            .Root.ItemWithPath("/October/25").Children
                            .Request().GetAsync();
```

or

```
await graphClient.Sites["site.sharepoint.com"].Drive
                            .Root.ItemWithPath("/2022/October/25").Children
                            .Request().GetAsync();
```